# How to make simple Navigation Based application using iOS 5.0 in latest Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have download the latest version of the xcode with iOS 5.0.
so, How to make simple Navigation Based application using iOS 5.0 in latest Xcode?

Comment: Isn't there a template in Xcode for Navigation based projects? There used to be one at least.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the master-detail project template in Xcode 4.2. I don't know why they took the Navigation-based template out but you can start from there.